# Where are the mistakes? (Delete button)

Tags: php, mysql, button, sql-delete

Let me know what is the right way to delete user from my database by form.

```
<?php
    if (!$_POST[update])
    {
        echo
        ("<form method=\"POST\">
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"delete\" name=\"Delete\" />
        </form>");
    }
    else{ 
         $update = mysql_query("DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM `users`;"); 
         or die(mysql_error());
}
// mysql_query("DELETE smth from users");
?>
```

Please correct the misstakes, and teach me why am I getting this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR) in Disk:...\xampp\htdocs\projectx\members.php on line ...

Comment: `!$_POST[update]` should be `!$_POST['update']` but you may have more problems than that.

Comment: it should be if( !isset($_POST['update']) ) { code here...}

Comment: Remove the `;` in `; or die`.

Comment: `DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM \`users\`` should be `DELETE  FROM \`users\` WHERE username = 'ddd'`.

Comment: Read a book on PHP. This isn't a site for learning the basic fundamentals of a language's syntax.

Comment: Some SQL doc could help too. It's a bit cruel, but programming isn't about typing random keywords hoping them to work together.

Answer (score 4):

You've got multiple typos and syntax errors:

1)

```
if (!$_POST['update'])
            ^------^--- missing quotes
```

2)

```
echo
(
^---  echo is not a function. brackets are not required
```

3)

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"delete\" name=\"Delete\" />
                                               ^^^^^^--- name mismatch
```

Your form is expecting `update` as a parameter, but your form can only ever send `Delete`, so your if()'s true clause will never trigger

4)

```
 $update = mysql_query("DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM `users`;"); or die(mysql_error());
                                                               ^---terminates statement
```

The last one is the cause of your error.

Comment: +1, echo is a **language construct**

Answer (score 0):

1. There should be no semicolon after `mysql_query()` statement:
   $update = mysql_query("DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM `users`;") or die(mysql_error());
2. You should not use parentheses `()` for `echo` as it is a language construct and not a function:

   echo "
            
         ";
3. You should use `''` for variable `keys` and should check if the corresponding key-value pair is empty like this:

   if (!empty($_POST['update']))
4. Correct this mysql query as this:

   $update = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE username = 'ddd'");
5. You should use the same name as you are retrieving using the `$_POST` variable on the server side.

   echo "
           
         ";

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE username = 'ddd'") or die(mysql_error());
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This has a ; before the or, so this:

```
$update = mysql_query("DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM `users`;"); or die(mysql_error());
```

Should become this:

```
 $update = mysql_query("DELETE username = 'ddd' FROM `users`;") or die(mysql_error());
```

You also should add a where in your delete statement... this form of delete does not work.

```
"DELETE FROM `users` WHERE  username = 'ddd' ;"
```